# 301 redirect via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect from http://example.com/contact-us to http://example.com/contact-us/offices
I have written following line in my .htaccess:

Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://example.com/contact-us/offices

But when I visit to http://example.com/contact-us then it redirects to http://example.com/contact-us/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/offices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this rule:

```
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://example.com/contact-us/offices
```

That is redirecting every URL that starts with `/contact-us/` new URL that is `/contact-us/offices`. Since redirecting URL also starts with `/contact-us/` therefore redirect will happen again and again causing a **redirect loop**. In order to avoid this situation use `RedirectMatch` that has regex support so that you can control the matching pattern.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact-us/?$ http://example.com/contact-us/offices
```

Don't forget to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of ?$ in ^/contact-us/?$

Comment: `/?$` makes`/` optional at the end of source URL, so it matches `/contact-us` or `/contact-us/`. `^` asserts start position and `$` asserts end position in regex.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to same host use below rule and then after clearing cache try this url to reach `http://example.com/contact-us/` use forward slash too.

```
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ /contact-us/offices/
```